# How to pass object/multiple arguments from Angularjs factory to spring controller

Tags: spring, angularjs, rest, spring-mvc, angularjs-directive

I am a newbie in Angularjs so please bear with me,
I have a requirement where I have to pass an Object to factory from controller.js in AngularJS , which calls a rest service and that object param is passed to Spring Controller. How Can I do that? The below approach which I am trying is giving null @ Spring controller.

**This is my Controller.js:**

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
            function showPosition(position) {

                $scope.PostLoc = {latitude: null, longitude: null };

                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var longi = position.coords.longitude;

                $scope.PostLoc.latitude = lat;
                $scope.PostLoc.longitude = longi;

                $scope.allresultsfinal = PostFactory.alllocresults.query({tag: $scope.PostLoc});

            }
```

**This is my Service factory:**

```
  alllocresults: $resource('/ngdemo/web/posts/loc/:tag', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: true, params: {tag: '@tag'} },
        create: {method: 'POST'}
    }),
```

**And my Spring controller Signature:**

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/loc/{tag}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
MatchResult resultsByUserLocation(@QueryParam(value = "tag") PostLoc tag) {
```

Please help me out with what I am missing and how can I get the object in my spring controller?

Any response will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a path variable on the URL, not a query parameter, so declare that in the method signature:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loc/{tag}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public
@ResponseBody
MatchResult resultsByUserLocation(@PathVariable("tag") PostLoc tag) {
    // ...
```

This assumes (perhaps incorrectly) that `PostLoc` extends `java.lang.String`. Note that you can't pass objects to URL path variables, only strings. If you want to pass in an object, you'd have to do that on the request body, or just pass some string ID and get the `PostLoc` from your model in the backend.

Comment: I tried it and it throws this error: "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ngdemo.model.PostLoc'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [ngdemo.model.PostLoc]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Comment: does that mean by using @ RequestBody , it should work? because I am using angular js, not sending any model

Comment: By using @RequestBody, it throwed Unsupported Media type!

Comment: i didn't say anything about using `@RequestBody`. what is `PostLoc`? where should it come from? is it persisted somewhere?